# rails console usage on nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console

I have a rails app. User has one profile and profile belongs to user.

If I call the following on profile in the console it works:

```
user = User.last
user.profile
```

But if I call these 2 below after defining users none of the calls work:

```
users = User.all
users.profile
users.profiles
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Profile` is an **association** of `User`, in `users = User.all`, `users` is a **relation**, so in order to show profiles of all users, you could do something like this:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  puts user.profile
end
```

In other words, each user has a profile, and you can show profile of any user, but what you were doing is try to show profile for all users.

If what you want is to show all Profiles, you could do it like this:

```
puts Profile.all.inspect
```

If you would like to show Profile of only some users, you could do it like this:

```
# this is a pseudo code
users = User.where(some_condition)

#actual example
users = User.where(first_name: 'Szilard')

puts Profiles.where(user_id: users.pluck(:id)).inspect
```

---

> first_name can be found in the profile model. In that case why I can't
>   call: users = User.joins(:profile).where(first_name: 'Szilard')

If first_name is a column of Profile, then it is the profile that you are querying:

```
Profile.where(first_name: 'Szilard').first
```

And this will return the first profile that has the specified name.

You can also join it to the user:

```
Profile.joins(:user).where(first_name: 'Szilard').first
```

This will return the first profile that has the specified name joined with the user that it belongs to.

Comment: Never use `#each` on `.all` since it causes in a [N+1 query problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)!

Comment: first_name can be found in the profile model. In that case why I can't call: users = User.joins(:profile).where(first_name: 'Szilard')

Comment: if the first_name is a column of Profile, then it should be the other way round: Profile.joins(:user).where(first_name: 'Szilard')

Comment: thx Tobias and bosskovic. Could you guys suggest me a good resource where I can read more about this topic (not rails guides)?

Answer (score 1):

The second call returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which includes an Array of all `Users`.

Since you want to have all `Profiles` of all `Users` I would recommend you to simply call the `.all` on `Profile`.

```
Profile.all
```

Another possible solution is to loop through the users and call every profile for each user seperately:

```
User.find_each do |user|   # Don't use `each`!
  user.profile   # => Profile
end
```

I hope this helps.